# From ActiveMQ to Java Bean

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to learn Camel on Fuse- within this example an ActiveMQ message is converted in a Java object named CustInfo using the Dozer component:

```
<camelContext id="context-43faded0-825e-454b-8037-c72122aa0418" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:sql.properties" id="properties"/>
  <endpoint uri="dozer:toCustInfo?sourceModel=homeloancust.CustInfo&amp;targetModel=org.blogdemo.homeloan.model.CustInfo&amp;unmarshalId=homeloancust&amp;mappingFile=toCustInfo.xml" id="toCustInfo"/>
  <dataFormats>
    <jaxb contextPath="homeloancust" id="homeloancust"/>
  </dataFormats>
  <route id="CustomerEvaluation">
      <from uri="activemq:queue:customer"/>
      <to ref="CustInfo" id="to3"/>
       . . . .
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

My question is, in case I don't need transformations in the Java object, can I convert the message into the Java class directly (without Dozer).
Tried with:

```
<bean id="CustInfo" class="homeloancust.CustInfo"/>
. . .
<to ref="CustInfo" id="to3"/>
```

Without success! Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the incoming message has a contract (which it should if it follows a good contract-first approach), then you can simply unmarshall the payload into a Java object using JAXB. If it doesn't have a contract, you can still annotate your Java class with JAXB annotations and unmarshall to it:

```
<unmarshal>
  <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="org.apache.camel.example"/>
</unmarshal>
```

http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html

Comment: Thanks for your help!